# WP - How to get the post ID in vc_gitem_post_meta.php

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm using Visual Composer in my Wordpress site.
I need to get the ID of the post which is rendered by grid builder (VC).

In this file, i tried the following things in this file: vc_gitem_post_meta.php:

```
$post = get_post();
$postid = $post->ID;
$id = get_the_ID();
$idloop = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

All of them are returning an empty result.

Any ideas?

Thanks for looking at the problem.

Comment: make the $post variable global at start and then try..

Comment: For more info visit codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Comment: Does not work since i globalled it already. @JohnySantiago

Comment: Can you share your complete code??

Comment: That's irrelevant, U have more than enough info in the original question.

Comment: Somehow answers of this question can solve your query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196353/wordpress-getting-post-data-for-post-grid-of-visual-composer

Comment: Your code isn't complete. As it lacks context. Where are you using this.? In a template file, in a filter/action. Some special Visual Composer construction?

Comment: The file is in the title. This is a part of the grid builder (in the intro). And the context is how to get the post id out of the loop to use in a custom query. @janw